# Hide the "Unknown Publisher" text in ClickOnce install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, certificate, clickonce, digital-signature

I would like to be sure on something:
is it possible to hide the "Unknown Publisher" field (replacing it b a real company name) in the ClickOnce installer without spending so much money in a authenticode provider?

I tried to create my own .pfx file, but even if I install it (the .cer & the .pfx) on the local computer (in trusted publisher), it's still shown as an unknown publisher program..?

Are we really supposed to spend so much money to prove we are not as creepy as VeriSign? Even in a local company for small app?

Comment: the whole sense in this is exactly to make sure the displayed publisher is "real"... so yes...

Comment: yes but, installing a custom certificate on the local computer couldn't be safe enough for this?

Comment: no - because it is not authenticated by a known CA

Comment: And there is no way for user to authenticated publisher by himself so?

Comment: No way you can count on... BTW: what are you trying to achieve ? some "hack" ?

Comment: I don't think that a hacker would easely install custom certificate in the thrusted publisher of a remote computer and if so, he wouldn't ask such of question because he would already have access to every part of the targeted computer.

Comment: $99 certificate from verisign https://winqual.microsoft.com/help/default.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is, if your company cannot afford an authenticode certificate or fails to see the value in purchasing it, it may be doomed.

You need a certificate.

Edit: $223 (http://www.sslshopper.com/microsoft-authenticode-certificates.html)?  This is a very minimal spend for any software company.

Comment: +1 if you can't afford that, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i ll try to talk about that to my boss.

Answer (score 3):

as comments has said, the whole purpose of certificates is to authenticate the provider. if anyone could have create a local certification as .NET allows, then how can the users trust it?

the money spent on the real certificate issues by a CA is to give credibility to the certificate so no one will be able to create certificates when he/she wishes.

Comment: I still think that installing user custom certificat would be enough (there is plenty more way to install such of virus without certificate btw), but according to both of you, it's obviously not Microsoft's point of view. So thank you for answers. :)

Comment: I 'm quietly sad to know that i must tell to my users to install program on their network with this kind of warning message... "hey man, you forgot to fill the company name"... "No it's ok, we should pay to ensure i am not trying to kill my own company... there is no other way..."

Comment: @Vloz - spend the pocket change for the certificate.